# Preserve ES6 import/export in Webpack?

Tags: webpack-2

I'd like to bundle my app leaving the `import` and `export` intact, so that a 3rd party app can include my bundle and take advantage of tree shaking.

I can't find a way to do it, I already don't include `es2015` babel preset, I only include `stage-2` and `react` presets.

Is it something possible with Webpack 2?

Comment: Can't you still achieve this by exposing different functionality using module.exports in different ways? import/export are pretty far away from being usable universally, so I'm not sure you want to actually do this. module.exports will achieve the same thing as far as I understand.

Comment: with multiple `module.exports` I have to manually import the specific bits I need (and it's only one level aware), with `import/export` it's everything automatic (and works on all the levels). I don't care about compatibility because I'll use this only internally.

Comment: What do you mean yo don't care about compatibility and will only use it internally? You just said in your question that you want it to be used by third parties...?

Comment: Yup, 3rd parties internally of my company.

Comment: I honestly don't know what this means "import/export it's everything automatic (and works on all the levels)". I'm not sure I can help you with what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's just that with `require('foo/bar')` you reduce the scope, but if `bar` exposes two functions, and you use just one of them, the other one will not be "tree shaked"

Comment: oh, so what you're saying is that you want to build a dependency, which can be tree shaken...for example, if it has two methods APP.do() and APP.hello(), and the user only uses one of the methods in their app, you want the dependency tree to shake out all the methods and dependencies that would have been compiled for methods they didn't use?

Comment: Yes that's basically what tree shaking is.

Comment: yes, i'm aware, but im not sure if you can tree shake imported modules. on a secondary level like that.

Comment: Yes, this is the purpose of the static nature of `import/export`, it can be statically analyzed and the bundler can import just what it actually needs.

Comment: but does it do that on a second level imports? i'm not saying you're wrong, i'm just surprised because i didn't know this and have seen no evidence from it in any of the analyzations of my bundles.

Comment: yes, at least, with Rollup this is the case. not sure about webpack but I guess it's the same

Comment: cool, i'll check it out. i had never been totally sure why i would use that. hope you find your answer!

Comment: @FezVrasta Hi there, have you found the way to let Webpack preserve import/export statement?